# Vue.js dynamic data collection for v-for

Tags: vuejs2

I'm pretty new to Vue.js, trying to get the following to work:

I have several arrays of objects in the root data of the view instance - let's say their names are `to do list, shopping list, meetings list`.

I also have three buttons with the same names.

If I hardcode `<div v-for='items in todolist'>`, of course it works, however:

What is the best way to have only one of those `div`s and dynamically change which array I'm looping through when we click one of the three buttons?

I'm not using ES6, just CDN included.

Basic example (not working) of what I'm trying to do can be found here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/415174/

There's a list of links that should change the v-for data collection for the list underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a computed property to return the correct array based on some other property.

For example

```js
data: {
  lists: {
    todos: [...],
    shopping: [...],
    meetings: [...],
  },
  currentList: 'todos'
},
computed: {
  items () {
    return this.lists[this.currentList]
  }
}
```

And in your template, use something like

```html
<p>
  <label>Todos <input type="radio" v-model="currentList" value="todos"></label>
  <label>Shopping <input type="radio" v-model="currentList" value="shopping"></label>
  <label>Meetings <input type="radio" v-model="currentList" value="meetings"></label>
</p>
<div v-for="item in items">
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/eywraw8t/415163/)

---

If you want to set the `currentList` property via a method, that's totally possible, eg

```html
<a v-for="list in ['todos', 'shopping', 'meetings']" @click="setCurrentList(list)">
  {{ list }}
</a>
```

and in your methods...

```js
methods: {
  setCurrentList(list) {
    this.currentList = list
  }
}
```

or even inline

```
@click="currentList = list"
```

Comment: Ah, I was trying something similar, but without the `this[this.currentList]` - didn't occur to me. Is there a way to set that with a method? Because all those A tags (radio buttons in your case) are dynamically generated?

Comment: @MaximilianBerbechelov sure, I'll add an example

Comment: This is almost what I'm trying to do. When I pass it directly - `setCurrentList(list)` it works, but when I pass it as a variable coming from somewhere (kind of like your example) it gets passed as a string

Comment: @MaximilianBerbechelov please update your question ([by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52769414/edit)) as your comment is not clear

Comment: I am sorry. Included a simple jsfiddle with the skeleton of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MaximilianBerbechelov I've updated your JSFiddle to work. You just had a couple of syntax errors and some mismatched strings. [Working version](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/eywraw8t/415184/)